Exact value of a trig angle
Is there a way I can get an exact value (in terms of radicals) for Cos[74Degree] ?
I tried:
FunctionExpand[Cos[74 Degree]]

ToRadicals[Cos[74 Degree]]

TrigToExp[Cos[74 Degree]] // FullSimplify

Cos[74 Degree] // RootReduce

ToRadicals[Cos[74 Degree]] // FullSimplify

None of them give me an exact value in terms of radicals!
All of them just convert this into a Sine form.

Cos[74 Degree] // FunctionExpand // TrigExpand //ToRadicals //Simplify?
Or convert to radians first to make it a little easier (though it's in a little longer LeafCountform):
Cos[74/360*2 Pi] // ToRadicals 

May be little shorter version than shown by ydd is Cos[74 Degree] // FunctionExpand // ToRadicals  gives -(1/2) (-1)^(37/90) (-1 + (-1)^(8/45))

Wow amaznig guys! Thanks so much...! By the way, does this work for ALL the angles from 1--> 360  (I assume in increments of 1 degree)?   Do All angles have exact forms? I assume they must

But wait, this is an imaginary number, this isn't right!!! (-1)^(37/90) // N -->   0.275637 + 0.961262 i  Seems like we just ignore the imaginary part....as the Cos is just 0.275....  Hmm...So why is there an img component there in result?

Don't forget (-1 + (-1)^(8/45)) part.

Doesn't matter: still has img part:   Cos[74  Degree] // FunctionExpand // ToRadicals // N

In addition half angles not have exact results also:   Cos[74.5  Degree] // FunctionExpand // ToRadicals

@Steve237 the imaginary part is a machine precision artifact:
Cos[74 Degree] // FunctionExpand // ToRadicals // N // Chop
To get exact results, you must supply exact angle:
Cos[149 /2 Degree] // FunctionExpand // ToRadicals

Yes. Try N[   ,1000] instead of N.

Sure, but why Chop? My point is that WHY is there even a very small imaginary component to this exact radical to begin with? We are just chopping/ignoring it, but in reality it IS still there! Why does Cosine of 74 degree even have a minute imaginary component?

@Steve237 - The radical expressions are composed with complex numbers. The imaginary parts of the complex numbers cancel each other; however, with finite precision there are small differences that leave residuals. If you express the values with exact real terms only, you will end up where you started with trig functions. Cos[74 Degree] // FunctionExpand // ToRadicals // Re // ComplexExpand

@Bob Hanlon : I never knew that about Trigs (that they have imaginary parts). Wow. After all these years! Thanks for enlightening me!

Why does this give ZERO-i?  Sin[34  Degree] // FunctionExpand // ToRadicals // N   it only has real part...strange

Last one: Is there a way to generate the EXACT value of each real and complex components? Of let's say (-1)^(37/90) // N   or:   Cos[74  Degree] // FunctionExpand // ToRadicals // N    instead of numerical components

Avoid using N.

No - then i do not get exact value of EACH component. I want REAL and Complex to be seperate EXACT values  and if I use //Re and //Im, then it gives results in terms of TRIG which I don't want! I want radicals

Cos[74 Degree] = Sin[(4 [Pi])/45] is exact value. Why you say it is not exact? If you need to use Radicals, then the use of complex numbers is inevitable by Galois theory.

Perhaps you need minimal polynomial? Then try MinimalPolynomial[Cos[74 Degree] // FunctionExpand][X].
